# Opposite of "Save" with respect to saving in a list

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm developing an application where with the ability to browse items and save them for later.  The behavior is essentially a user will look at items, and if the items are not present on their list I present the option "save", but if the user already has that item saved I would like to present an option to remove it from their list.  The best I have found is:

"save" - meaning save this item to your list
"remove" - meaning remove this item from your list

Are there any other words that would fit better?

Comment: You might do better at http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Some UIs will show two columns one for "available" items and one for "Added" items with two buttons in between for moving selected items from one column to the other.  Chris's *Add/Remove* works perfectly for this.

Answer (score 3):

If you want words that are a natural pair, I would go with *add* and *remove*.  The natural pair of *save* in a computing context is *delete,* which is not appropriate in this case, since nothing is being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

To remove an item from a list is to "**Excise**" it, which implies that no gap remains – i.e., all remaining list items are concatenated (if necessary) and left contiguous when the operation is complete.